# Google analytics two part goal

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I've built a site which has forms with event tracking codes, but now the client wants to create goals for specific landing page -> form submission

And all the forms have the same tracking codes at the moment.

Looking in google analytics goal setup it seems I can only add one part goals e.g. by URL or by event tracking code but not

if {this page and this tracking code}
record {this goal}

Is this possible or do I just need to make tracking codes for each individual form on every page?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't combine event and page conditions in the goals configuration. You'll need to customize your tracking codes to track this, and this can be quite tricky if your form is on some other page than landing page.
By the way, with the current setup, your client can see exactly the same information in Behavior > Site Content > Landing page report in Google Analytics